# My Chrome browser got hacked on Win-10...can't update it and can't send Gmail

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, virus, gmail

I think my Chrome browser (on Win-10) got hacked...can't update it and can't send Gmail.  (Chrome and GMail works fine on another computer which is running Win-7).

In Chrome, it shows: "Updates are disabled by your administrator.", even tho
it seems up-to-date, as it is the same version as on the Win-7 system.
EDIT: Chrome version shows as "Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)"

As a workaround, my Gmail works fine under 'WaterFox' browser (on the
Win-10 computer).

I got a notification that Win-10 builtin virus scanner successfully dealt with some threat(s), but the symptoms persist.  I'm unclear how to get the NAME(S)
of whatever threats it found.

Next, I did a scan using 'herdProtect', but it found nothing.  (Makes sense, since builtin anti-virus already dealt with the culprit.)

Any recommendations on how to proceed, to fix those symptoms on the damaged Win-10 computer???

Comment: What happens when you try to access gmail?

Comment: Re : Updates are disabled by your administrator."  :   what (else) do you have in chrome:policy ?     Consider running Chrome Policy Remover : https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/chrome/0dysxZXJto4/

Comment: @David Schwartz: So, in GMail, most functions work.  But, when  I click 'compose' to create a new outgoing msg, NOTHING...no outgoing small window pops up.  Also, I received (in spam) a msg from an old DaniWeb acct, suggesting that I change my pwd. So, I go there and just delete that acct, since I don't want/need it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the symptoms have been healed...not sure what fixed it.

!) Maybe the anti-virus software learned how to isolate/remove it.
  Or
2) Running the 'Chrome Policy Remover' may have fixed it.  [ If it did,
it was a 'delayed fix', as it wasn't gone immediately after.  But, by
the next day, the Chrome-browser (same version as mentioned above) was
running normally. ]

Bottom line...we can consider this thread closed.

Cheers...